# Wordpress woo commerce with page restrictions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, membership

I am building wordpess sites with woocommerce.

Now I have 2 kind of products.

Product 1: When some one purchases this product they will be able to login with their id and access courses. 
Product 2: When they purchase they done get any acess to courses the max exception they can have is they can login and see their invoice they cant access anything.

So is there any membership plugin which makes this difference based on paid amount or purchased product.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the figured this out... Please check the url below url

http://wpthemetutorial.com/2013/09/10/restricting-content-based-product-purchase-woocommerce/